# Variable names inferred from grib2 files through Nio.open_file - or xr.open_dataset with engine pynio

Tags: python-2.7, python-xarray, grib

I am using the data found [here](ftp://ftpprd.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/cfs/prod/cfs/) (Note, these are rotating files of forecast data, so the actual date will change as time goes by, you might need to update the date in my example in a few days)

```
!wget ftp://ftpprd.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/cfs/prod/cfs/cfs.20180524/00/6hrly_grib_01/pgbf2018052400.01.2018052400.grb2


tmp2 = xr.open_dataset('pgbf2018052400.01.2018052400.grb2', 
                   engine='pynio')
```

which is read as

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                   (lat_0: 181, lon_0: 360, lv_AMSL1: 4, lv_HTGL6: 2, lv_ISBL0: 37, lv_ISBL4: 32, lv_ISBL5: 2, lv_PVL2: 2, lv_SIGL3: 4)
Coordinates:
  * lon_0                     (lon_0) float32 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 ...
  * lv_ISBL0                  (lv_ISBL0) float32 100.0 200.0 300.0 500.0 ...
  * lv_ISBL5                  (lv_ISBL5) float32 50000.0 100000.0
  * lv_ISBL4                  (lv_ISBL4) float32 1000.0 2000.0 3000.0 5000.0 ...
  * lat_0                     (lat_0) float32 90.0 89.0 88.0 87.0 86.0 85.0 ...
  * lv_PVL2                   (lv_PVL2) float32 -2e-06 2e-06
  * lv_AMSL1                  (lv_AMSL1) float32 1829.0 2743.0 3658.0 4572.0
Dimensions without coordinates: lv_HTGL6, lv_SIGL3
Data variables:
    TOZNE_P0_L200_GLL0        (lat_0, lon_0) float32 ...
    HGT_P0_L100_GLL0          (lv_ISBL0, lat_0, lon_0) float32 ...
    VVEL_P0_L100_GLL0         (lv_ISBL0, lat_0, lon_0) float32 ...
    UGRD_P0_L6_GLL0           (lat_0, lon_0) float32 ...
    HGT_P0_L7_GLL0            (lat_0, lon_0) float32 ...
    CIN_P0_2L108_GLL0         (lat_0, lon_0) float32 ...
    PRES_P0_L109_GLL0         (lv_PVL2, lat_0, lon_0) float32 ...
    UGRD_P0_L7_GLL0           (lat_0, lon_0) float32 ...
    UGRD_P0_L109_GLL0         (lv_PVL2, lat_0, lon_0) float32 ...
    PRES_P0_L7_GLL0           (lat_0, lon_0) float32 ...
    PLI_P0_2L108_GLL0         (lat_0, lon_0) float32 ...
```

and many other variables

my struggle right now is to understand how these variable names (i.e. PLI_P0_2L108_GLL0) are generated.

If I run directly Nio:

```
f = Nio.open_file('pgbf2018052400.01.2018052400.grb2')
print(f)
```

I get:

```
Nio file:   pgbf2018052400.01.2018052400.grb2
   global attributes:
   dimensions:
      lat_0 = 181
      lon_0 = 360
      lv_ISBL0 = 37
      lv_AMSL1 = 4
      lv_PVL2 = 2
      lv_SIGL3 = 4
      lv_ISBL4 = 32
      lv_ISBL5 = 2
      lv_HTGL6 = 2
   variables:
      float TMP_P0_L6_GLL0 [ lat_0, lon_0 ]
         center :   US National Weather Service - NCEP (WMC)
         production_status :    Operational products
         long_name :    Temperature
         units :    K
         _FillValue :   1e+20
         grid_type :    Latitude/longitude
         parameter_discipline_and_category :    Meteorological products, Temperature
         parameter_template_discipline_category_number :    [0, 0, 0, 0]
         level_type :   Maximum wind level
         level :    0
         forecast_time :    0
         forecast_time_units :  hours
         initial_time : 05/24/2018 (00:00)
      float TMP_P0_L7_GLL0 [ lat_0, lon_0 ]
```

and much more, but the names of the variables are there. So it is something defined at Nio level (I think)

However, when I inspect the data with wgrib2 I have:

```
wgrib2 pgbf2018052400.01.2018052400.grb2

1:0:d=2018052400:PRES:mean sea level:anl:
2:66570:d=2018052400:HGT:1 mb:anl:
3:102113:d=2018052400:TMP:1 mb:anl:
4:118939:d=2018052400:RH:1 mb:anl:
5:122609:d=2018052400:SPFH:1 mb:anl:
6:141106:d=2018052400:VVEL:1 mb:anl:
7.1:219137:d=2018052400:UGRD:1 mb:anl:
7.2:219137:d=2018052400:VGRD:1 mb:anl:
8:283014:d=2018052400:ABSV:1 mb:anl:
9:319471:d=2018052400:O3MR:1 mb:anl:
10:372630:d=2018052400:HGT:2 mb:anl:
11:408159:d=2018052400:TMP:2 mb:anl:
12:425397:d=2018052400:RH:2 mb:anl:
13:427490:d=2018052400:SPFH:2 mb:anl:
14:459259:d=2018052400:VVEL:2 mb:anl:
15.1:517010:d=2018052400:UGRD:2 mb:anl:
15.2:517010:d=2018052400:VGRD:2 mb:anl:
16:580043:d=2018052400:ABSV:2 mb:anl:
17:617506:d=2018052400:O3MR:2 mb:anl:
18:672805:d=2018052400:HGT:3 mb:anl:
19:707799:d=2018052400:TMP:3 mb:anl:
20:725593:d=2018052400:RH:3 mb:anl:
21:729682:d=2018052400:SPFH:3 mb:anl:
22:765030:d=2018052400:VVEL:3 mb:anl:
23.1:828383:d=2018052400:UGRD:3 mb:anl:
23.2:828383:d=2018052400:VGRD:3 mb:anl:
24:892759:d=2018052400:ABSV:3 mb:anl:
25:931422:d=2018052400:O3MR:3 mb:anl:
26:979930:d=2018052400:HGT:5 mb:anl:
```

The problem I have is that I am trying to run an open_mfdataset in xarray to concatenate along Forecast start time and Forecast Lead time thousands of these little files, unfortunately the variable names (of the same quantity, say convective precipitation, which in the grib file is ACPC) read by xarray change throughout the Lead time (that goes from 6 hour to about 6480 hour)... going from ACPCP_P8_L1_GLL0_acc, to ACPCP_P8_L1_GLL0_acc6h, to ACPCP_P0_L1_GLL0, making things complicated.

I tried to overwrite the variable names with the preprocessing function, but sometimes doesn't seem to be a consistent change, making things complicated.

Anyone knows where the string like "_P0_L6_GLL0" attached to the grib variable name come from? anyway to modify that?

Comment: I posted this on github and 1) figured out based on the website how the name is formed, 2) how to drop part of the text, but not the whole thing. https://github.com/NCAR/pynio/issues/19#